# how can i download pytorch manually?

Tags: python, pip, pytorch, download, package

hello im trying to use some python programs that need pytorch and when trying to install it using the command

```
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118
```

this is the error i get

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000183D80F60B0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed')': /whl/cu118/torch/                                                     
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000183D80F63E0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed')': /whl/cu118/torch/                                                     
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000183D80F6590>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed')': /whl/cu118/torch/                                                     
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000183D80F6740>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed')': /whl/cu118/torch/                                                     
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000183D80F68F0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed')': /whl/cu118/torch/                                                     
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch (from versions: none)                              ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch                                                                         WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.
```

i can somewhat solve the problem by using a vpn but the problem is pytorch is a very large package and it keeps getting interrupted and i have to start from the beginning again and again so i need a way to download the package manually with download managers that support download resuming and was wondering how it can be done as i am a noob when it comes to python thank you.

Comment: are you on linux, mac or windows just to clarify ?

Comment: i'm on windows 10

Comment: one way would be to go to https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118.
Then select torch.
Download the file corresponding to the pytorch and python versions you want.
Then use pip to install it with the whl file instead of the --index-url option.
After that if you really need it, just do `pip install torchvision torchaudio`.
If the first download still is stuck, then it is not a problem with Pytorch server but maybe with your computer.

Comment: Can you install other pip packages without connection errors?

Comment: Just downloaded torch-2.0.0+cu118-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl without any trouble.

Comment: downloading it from https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118 fixed the issue thank you Toyo

Answer (score 0):

One way would be:

1. Go to [download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118](https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118).
2. Select `torch`.
3. Download the file corresponding to the pytorch and python versions you want.
4. Use pip to install it with the whl file instead of the `--index-url` option.

After that if you really need it, just do `pip install torchvision torchaudio`. 
If the first download is still stuck, then it is not a problem with Pytorch server but maybe with your computer.

Note: tested with the file `torch-2.0.0+cu118-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl`